# Information from website to Java

Tags: java, html, swing

In Java, I have a chatting application. In it, I have a version checker mainly to make sure you couldn't for eg. Connect to a newly updated server as a 2 year old client, it wouldn't work.

On the launcher, I have display of a webpage I setup to show the changelog.
What I am trying to achieve is have a JLabel saying:

'Your application is up to date.'
'Your application is not up to date.'

To do this, I am thinking I would have to send some sort of information from the site to my application. Like, maybe a string containing the version, and Java will do the rest to check if it's up to date.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of a server are you ruining?

Comment: create a json file in your server

Comment: Im not trying to ruin any server. I am basically trying to send information from a webpage to my application.

Comment: What will I do with a .json file? I am new to the 'internet' side of Java and have never used a .json file either.

Comment: json should containing your last app version .and your desktop app read that file over internet and check is it uptodate

Comment: Ok, can you please show me how to do it? I am hopeless. :P

Comment: You do have client and server, right?  How do they talk?

Comment: They talk with Sockets, ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: i'm sorry.i was misunderstand ur question .i thought it was desktop application

Comment: Oh, thats OK. It's still being worked on in eclipse. I think I'm onto a dodgy but good solution. Will report back in about 10.

Comment: Ok yes, I have found a solution!

Comment: good luck for your application

Comment: Mmmm got to wait to answer though. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, is probably a nicer, cleaner way to do it, but I did it.

Basically on my changelog.html page, I have down the bottom hidden in white (blends with background) a little bit of text saying "Current Version: 1.0" So then in Java, I got the page source and dissected each part of it until all I had left was the '1.0'

So here is the part with the version:

```
<font color='white'><p>Current Version: 1.0</font>
```

And in Java, I did this:

```
private void getVersion() {
    String source;

    // Try to set a String to the webpages source.
    try {
        source = getUrlSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Split the text in half.
    String[] v = source.split("<font color='white'><p>Current Version: ");

    // Gets the part after 'Current Version: '
    String v2 = v[1];

    // Removes the end bit.
    v2 = v2.replace("</font></html>", "");

    // All we have left is '1.0'
    System.out.println(v2);

}
```

Thanks for the comments too. Got me going on the solution.

Comment: I'd investigate jsoupor xpath. I'd also investigate having a means by which a client must validate is version when it first connects to a server, as part of the protocol

Comment: Yeah, currently it's just a small project i'm working on and wanted a simple way to do it. As I get more into it I will most likely do as said.